# How to fix wsl bash error when flutter is added to environment variable?

Tags: flutter, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

When I tried to add flutter to windows environment, my WSL is not happy Im getting this error.

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: use -[v]S to pass options in shebang lines
```

[image]

This will only happen if I add flutter to windows environment variables.

Any tips how I can fix this?

Comment: Remove the carriage return character  (displayed as \r)  after "bash".

Comment: @user1934428 Im not running any script, or created my own script. That error will only show if I add the flutter binary to windows environment and when I enter to WSL. Iam not running any script at that time.

Comment: I never worked with wsl, but I guess that running `wsl` creates a bash process. This means that bash will run its startup files. During this bash startup, a faulty `/usr/bin/env` command is encountered. For debugging, I would first do inside your bash shell a `bash --login` from the command line. If the error appears here again, it will likely be trivial to find the culprit.

Comment: do you have any idea how should I troubleshoot this? executing `bash --login` shows the same errors. BTW whatever command you set on the `ENV VAR` on windows will be also available on `wsl`.

Comment: Same error is great! So next you do a `bash --login -x`, and in front of your astonished eyes will unfold a trace of all commands processed  by bash during startup. From this trace, you will see exactly where the error occurs. :-) This will allow you to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is a Windows-formatted text file, which bash doesn't like, not even in WSL. Save it without the carriage returns.

Comment: It will only show that error if I enter to WSL from windows. Im not executing any script. Added screenshot on the question

Comment: Something is executing a script, because that error message indicates that the first line of the script is `#!/usr/bin/env bash` with a carriage return. Maybe it's called from your .bashrc or .bash_profile, maybe it's the `wsl` command itself, but somewhere there is a windows-formatted shell script in the loop. What exactly did you do to "add flutter"?

Comment: I just follow the official installation instruction from the flutter website to add the ```C:\flutter\bin``` directory to the user environment variables. So that I can execute flutter commands to windows console

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem was, when I add the flutter command on the windows environment variables path, all the windows `env` will be also carried on the `WSL` this will in turn make the windows `flutter` command have a priority.

And when I enable the flutter bash completion

```bash
source <(flutter bash-completion)
```

this will use the flutter executable from windows and bash doesn't like it.

The simple fix is to priority the `wsl` local flutter binary.

```bash
export PATH=~/devtools/flutter/bin/:$PATH
```

This fixed the problem.